How can I check whether a deployment stack exists in the current subscription using Azure CLI?
I want to check whether a deployment stack exists before attempting to delete it:
    az stack sub delete \
      --name ${{ env.deploymentStackName }} \
      --action-on-unmanage deleteAll \
      --yes

Other Azure CLI commands support the exists sub-command, but that's not the case for az stack sub:
az group exists --name mygroup

How can I check whether the deployment stack exists prior to attempting to delete it?


How can I check whether the deployment stack exists prior to attempting to delete it?

To check whether the deployment stack exists before deleting it, you can use the below PowerShell script with the relevant functional commands according to meet your requirements.
$stackdeploy=(Get-AzSubscriptionDeploymentStack -Name jahstack).Name
if($stackdeploy){
 write-Host "Deployment exists..."
 Remove-AzSubscriptionDeploymentStack -Name $stackdeploy
}else
 {
   write-Host "Stack deployment not exists"
 }

Output:
Below is the output of checking and deleting the deployment stack if it exists. Once it is executed, I have tried to retrieve the same deployment stack using Get-AzSubscriptionDeploymentStack and the output is not found. It means that it got deleted successfully after checking the existence.

If you want to use the Azure CLI, firstly retrieve the deployment stack name with below command.
stackdeploy=$(az stack sub show --name xxxx --query name)

Once it is done, you need to use a if-else to check the existence and then delete it as there is no direct CLI command for it.
Note: I would suggest you go with the above given detailed PowerShell script rather than using CLI.

If Get-AzSubscriptionDeploymentStack -Name jahstack results in an error, doesn’t it result in another error to reference the Name property?

Thank you, I like the answer

Glad you liked it! @Shuzheng
